# Pass pointer array to function

Tags: c, arrays, function-pointers, fopen

I am trying to pass a file pointer array to a function (not sure about the terminology).  Could anyone please explain the proper way to send 'in[2]'?  Thank you.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    void openfiles (FILE **in[], FILE **out)
    {
        *in[0] = fopen("in0", "r");
        *in[1] = fopen("in1", "r");
        *out   = fopen("out", "w");
    }

    void main()
    {
        FILE *in[2], *out;

        openfiles (&in, &out);
        fprintf(out, "Testing...");

        exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
void openfiles (FILE *in[], FILE **out)
{
    in[0] = fopen("in0", "r");
    in[1] = fopen("in1", "r");
    *out   = fopen("out", "w");
}
```

And call it `openfiles (in, &out);`. Also, "pointer array" is ambiguous. Perhaps call it "array of FILE pointers" ?

Answer (score 0):

You need `pointer to array of FILE* type` , Do as I did in below function. Also add `()` parenthesis like `(*in)` to **overwrite precedence** Because by default `[]` has higher precedence over `*` operator. SEE: [Operator Precedence](https://www.cs50.net/resources/cppreference.com/operator_precedence.html)

```
void openfiles (FILE* (*in)[2], FILE **out){
    (*in)[0] = fopen("in0", "r");
    (*in)[1] = fopen("in1", "r");
    *out   = fopen("out", "w");
}
```

My example over string can be useful to understand the concept:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void f(char* (*s)[2]){
 printf("%s %s\n", (*s)[0],(*s)[1]);    
} 
int main(){
 char* s[2];
 s[0] = "g";
 s[1] = "ab";
 f(&s);
 return 1;
}
```

output:

```
g ab
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/WDLBBLMN)

For **OP**: also read Lundin's comments to my answer Quit helpful!

Comment: Note however that in the special case of a function parameter, `FILE* (*in)[2]` is equivalent to `FILE* in[2]`, both are _array pointers_ to an array of 2 FILE*.

Comment: @Lundin I am bit unsure. Ok then In function parameter does `char* (*s)[2]` == `char* s[2]` **?**

Comment: @Lundin I [**checked here**](http://codepad.org/aHU3VcQ4) And You are **CORRECT**.  In function parameter does `char* (*s)[2] == char* s[2]`.. Thanks :)

Comment: Function parameters are quite confusing. No matter if you type a formal array pointer declaration as you did, or if you type something that looks like an array declaration as I did, or if you merely type FILE*, it will all boil down to a pointer in the end.

Comment: Though please note that the version in your answer is correct, it is the most formal and stylistically correct way of declaring such a parameter. But it can be hard to read and understand for the average programmer.

Comment: Thanks Lundin :) it was helpful for me.