# What is the difference between the following declarations in C?

Tags: c, pointers, declaration

what's the difference between these 2 declarations:

```
char (*ptr)[N];
```

vs.

```
char ptr[][N];
```

thanks.

Comment: [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) is wonderful.  (Though it calls the first one a syntax error.)

Comment: (Doesn't like ptr as a var name and wants a literal dimension.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**(1)**  declaration

```
char (*ptr)[N];
```

`ptr` is `pointer to char array of size N`  following code will help you to on how to use it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 10
int main(){
 char array[N] = "yourname?";
 char (*ptr)[N] = &array;
 int i=0;
 while((*ptr)[i])
  printf("%c",(*ptr)[i++]);
}
```

output:

```
yourname?
```

See: [Codepad](http://codepad.org/28PEJAUN)

**(2.A)**

Where as `char ptr[][N];` is an invalid expression gives error: `array size missing in 'ptr'`.

But `char ptr[][2] = {2,3,4,5};` is a valid declaration that is 2D char array. Below example:

```
int ptr[][3] = {{1,2,3,4,5}, {5,6,7,8,9}, {6,5,4,3,2}};
```

Create an *int array of 3 rows and 5 cols*. [Codepade-Example](http://codepad.org/l5z4DFTe)

**(2.B)**  Special case of a function parameter!

As function parameter `char ptr[][N];` is a valid expression. that means `ptr` can point a `2D char array of N columns`.

example: Read comments in output

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fun(char arr[][5]){
  printf("sizeof arr is %d bytes\n", (int)sizeof arr);
}
int main(void) {
  char arr[][6] = {{'a','b'}, {'c','d'}, {'d','e'}};
  printf("sizeof arr is %d bytes\n", (int)sizeof arr);
  printf("number of elements: %d\n", (int)(sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]));
  fun(arr);
  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
sizeof arr is 6 bytes   // 6 byte an Array 2*3 = 6
number of elements: 3   // 3 rows
sizeof arr is 4 bytes   // pointer of char 4 bytes
```

To view this example running: [codepad](http://codepad.org/D9XARiTX)

Comment: The OP probably meant to ask the difference between 2 types, not 2 declarations. `char ptr[][N]` is a valid description of function parameter.

Comment: @icepack I think he might asking of not function pointer then He specifies, Also he added an `;`. That why. Any ways you are **CORRECT**

Comment: @icepack Coincidence is I am asked [second time about function parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151803/pass-pointer-array-to-function?answertab=active#tab-top) today. Good point.

Comment: 10x. did i get it right: in the first case ptr is a pointer to char array, while in the second case ptr is a pointer to a 2D char array?

Comment: @user1980750 See In `char ptr[][2] = {2,3,4,5};` ,`ptr` is not pointer but char 2D array. But if `char ptr[][N];` appears in function parameter like `fun(char ptr[][2])` then ptr is pointer

Comment: @user1980750 see the updated answer I added an example with output. Please read comments. –

Comment: wow thanks a lot! it's a bit confusing.. but i think i understood it. thanks again!

Comment: @user1980750 Yes, Function parameters are quite confusing.

Answer (score 2):

First is **declare ptr as pointer to array N of char**
Second is **declare ptr as array of array N of char**

Plz refer [link](http://cdecl.org/)

Answer (score 1):

The first declares a pointer to an N-long array, the other declares an two dinemsional array.
Note: They *can* be used to achieve the similar functionality, but they don't mean the same!

Answer (score 0):

1.ptr is pointer to character array of size N
2. ptr looks like a double dimensional array but number of rows is not provided.In 2-D array both number of rows and column is compulsory as compiler will decide how many bytes should be assigned to array by (number of row*number of column*size of data type).This declaration may work fine as below:

```
char[][2]={
           {'a','b'}
          };
```

as here compiler will look and understand that there is one row.or when a two dimensional array is passed on as a function argument,the number of columns(second dimension) must be provided by compulsion,passing number of rows is not compulsory in function definition.