# Modifying the values of a 2d array of reference in a function

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

This program must have a function that can accept 2 arrays and return their product in a third array.  All of the arrays must be 2d, and a separate function must complete the multiplication of the elements memberwise.  When I run this in visual studio I get the error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x003f15ec in program4.exe: 0xC0000005:  
Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

This could be due to my lack of knowledge about C++, but I think I may have made a syntax mistake or something.
Here is the program:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void ProductArrays(int[3][4], int[3][4], int** array3[3][4]);


void main()
{
int array1[3][4] = { {1,3,5,7}, {9,11,13,15},  {17,19,21,23} };
int array2[3][4] = { {2,4,6,8}, {10,12,14,16}, {18,20,22,24} };
int** array3[3][4] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

ProductArrays(array1, array2, array3);

system("pause");
return;
}

void ProductArrays(int array1[3][4], int array2[3][4], int** array3[3][4])
{
int i,j;
for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
          **array3[i][j] = array1[i][j] * array2[i][j];
        }
    }
return;
}
```

Comment: `void main()` is non-standard. Use `int main()` and either `return 0;` or leave it out altogether. A good compiler should not accept `void main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)**
The  declaration for array3 is wrong as you required.

```
int** array3[3][4] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

You need this If I correctly understand you question:

```
int array3[3][4] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

**(3)**
You are getting error because you were creating 2D array of pointers those are pointing to NULL (`0`) and you are assigning to `0` location.

```
**array3[i][j] = array1[i][j] * array2[i][j];
               ^ assign to `0` location
```

**(2)**
Declare you function like:

```
void ProductArrays(int array1[3][4], int array2[3][4], int (*array3)[4])
{ //                                                          ^ notice
int i,j;
for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
           array3[i][j] = array1[i][j] * array2[i][j];
        // ^ remove **  
        }
    }
return;
}
```

call it from main like:

```
ProductArrays(array1, array2, array3);
```

Additional point, my answer is pass by address, and @Barry's answer is pass by reference. In C++ Both are allowed. (*in C only pass by address is possible*)

Pass by reference having power of pointers but simple to use like value variables So @Barry's answer is better. consider my answer for understanding points of view.

Comment: Note that `int (*array3)[4]`, `int array3[3][4]` are equivalent as a function parameter.

Comment: @JesseGood Yes `int array3[3][4])` and `int (*array3)[4]` are same in function argument. Parameter arguments confuses me :) ..Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me better understand by address and by reference.

Comment: @Radd Glad that it helped you. I would suggest you read Jesses Good's comment to my answer. note: [declaration in function Parliaments are bit different then simple declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157133/what-is-the-difference-between-the-following-declarations-in-c?answertab=votes#tab-top) read lined answer too.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean for `array3` to be a reference to a 2d array of pointers, but it's actually a 2d array of `int**`. So when you do the multiplication, this part:

```
**array3[i][j]
```

Is trying to dereference what's in `array3[i][j]`, which is 0, hence the AccessViolation. I think you probably mean the signature to be:

```
void ProductArrays(int array1[3][4], int array2[3][4], int (&array3)[3][4])
```

And declare array3 to be of the same type as array1 and array2.

Comment: `int (&)[3][4]`, declare `array3` as `int array3[3][4]`, and pass via `array3`.

Comment: `int& array3[3][4]` is an array of references (which is not allowed). I think you meant `int (&array3)[3][4]`.