# Inconsistent lvalue required error when incrementing array variable

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I am getting "lvalue required as increment operand" while doing `*++a`. Where I am going wrong? I thought it will be equivalent to `*(a+1)`. This behaviour is weird as `*++argv` is working fine. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
  printf("Arg is:  = %s\n", *++argv);

  int a1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};    
  int a2[] = {7,8,9,10,11,12};
  int *a[2];

  a[0] = a1;
  a[1] = a2;

  printf("ptr  = %d\n", *++a);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void main` is not legal. Use `int main`.

Comment: I am not able to understand how *argv[] is acting like a pointer while *a[] do not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a` is a constant(array name) you can't change its value by doing `++a`,  that is equal to `a = a + 1`.
You might wanted to do `*a = *a + 1` (increment 0 indexed value), for this  try `*a++` instead. notice I have changed `++` from  prefix to postfix.

Note: `char* argv[]` is defined as function parameter and `argv` is pointer *variable* of `char**` type ( `char*[]`).
Whereas in your code `int* a[]` is not a function parameter. Here `a` is an array of int type (`int*`)(array names are constant). Remember declaration in function parameter and normal declarations are different.

Further, by using `++` with `argv` and `a` you just found one difference, one more interesting difference you can observe if you use `sizeof` operator to print there size. for example check this working code [Codepade](http://codepad.org/BAVZdN0t)

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int* a[2];
    printf(" a: %u, argv: %u", sizeof(a), sizeof(argv));
    return 1;
}
```

Output is:

```
a: 8, argv: 4
```

Address size in system is four bytes. output `8` is size of array `a` consists of two elements of type int addresses (because `a` is array), whereas `4` is size of `argv` (because `argv` is pointer).

Comment: I am not able to understand how *argv[] is acting like a pointer while *a[] do not. Why *++argv is working?

Comment: @Bhaskar `argv` is function parameter  and `*a[]` is not

Comment: @Bhaskar if you can understand double pointers/2D arrays then you check [one more example show difference between declarations in function pointers and formal declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157133/what-is-the-difference-between-the-following-declarations-in-c/15157256#15157256)

Comment: +1  for *Declaration in function parameter and normal declarations are different.*   and `sizeof` example . :)

Comment: @Abhineet Ahaa Guru!! thanks :)  did you read my other answers?

Comment: Chha gaye Guru...Jaise titli udti aa jati hai phoolon k paas, waise humne bhi aapke other answers check kiye hain :-) And I do follow you. Your answers are very concise and correct. :-)

Comment: @Abhineet very very thanks Abhineet! I learned from [RolandoMySQLDBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29047/how-to-update-same-table-on-deletion-in-mysql)'s answer. I got many good answers from him. He always explains from fundamental. That is I started too, in my answers. I generally updates my answer to improve representation and English because I give reference of my profile @ SO in my CV. That is the reason I improved your one answer to guide you.

Answer (score 4):

`++a` and `a + 1` are not equivalent. `++a` is the same as `a = a + 1`, i.e it attempts to modify `a` and requires `a` to be a modifiable lvalue. Arrays are not modifiable lvalues, which is why you cannot do `++a` with an array.

`argv` declaration in `main` parameter list is not an array, which is why you can do `++argv`. When you use `a[]` declaration in function parameter list, this is just syntactic sugar for pointer declaration. I.e.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

is equivalent to

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

But when you declare an array as a local variable (as in your question), it is indeed a true array, not a pointer. It cannot be "incremented".

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are not pointers.  `a` is an array; you cannot increment an array.

Comment: @Bhaskar: `argv` isn't an array, it's a pointer; see http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html.

Comment: @Bhaskar: No, `argv` is actually a pointer. When you declare a function parameter as an array its type is adjusted to the corresponding pointer type. `argv`'s type is actually `char**`.