# C program error--invalid lvalue in increment

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void main(void) 
{ 

char* p ="sahil"; 
printf("%c,%c,%c,%c",*p,*(++p),*(p++),*p); 

}
```

result:

```
h,h,s,h
```

it should be:

```
s,a,a,h
```

Could someone explain the result.

---

one more situation:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void main(void) 
{ 

char p[] ="sahil";                            <<<< Change in the declaration 
printf("%c,%c,%c,%c",*p,*(++p),*(p++),*p);    <<<<Line 7 

}
```

Result-In function 'main':

```
Line 7: error: invalid lvalue in increment 
Line 7: error: invalid lvalue in increment
```

Plz explain

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about multiple _frequently-asked_ questions.

Comment: Fix the bug and the mystery will go away.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540026/inconsistent-lvalue-required-error-when-incrementing-array-variable?rq=1 for the second part.

Comment: @devnull: as a beginner, how would you search for this?

Comment: Do not write code that has undefined behavior. It usually looks ugly

Comment: @KarolyHorvath (1) post-increment, pre-increment (2) error: invalid lvalue in increment.

Comment: @devnull: I agree with (2). searching for the error message is a beginner level task (though a lot of people fail this step). I disagree with (1), you're expecting too much.. and note that there are no relevant google hits for it, which shows how localized your query is.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Fair enough.  I disagree with the fact that every other _beginner_ runs into the same undefined behavior.  It seems more like an attempt to ask _smart questions_.

Comment: I wish they were that "smart" :)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Moreover, if one is familiar with the operators in question chances are that one would also be familiar with the terminology.

Comment: assuming they learnt the terminology in english... and realising that the combination of the two that causes the problems. i'm telling you, you're expecting too much ;)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Is it banned to ask beginner level questions here.All i  had was a doubt,it could be any level as such.

Comment: @SahilChodhary: you've got the answer, so it's not a big deal.